# Entity Framework BulkInsert

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have created BulkInsert method as below:

```
public void BulkInsertUsers(IEnumerable<tblUsers> users)
{
    using (var ctx = new Entities())
    {
        ctx.BulkInsert(users);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Mu problem is that `ctx.BulkInsert(users);` returns error:

> Type 'Infrastructure.EF.tblUser' is not found in context 'Infrastructure.EF.Entities'

In debug mode, when I expanded ctx variable, I've found that some entities have value like:

```
System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Automation.Infrastructure.EF.EntityName>
```

and some other have:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
FROM [dbo].[tbl] AS [Extent1]
```

For those entities which have SELECT value, BulkInsert works fine.
I am using

> EntityFramework.BulkInsert, Version=6.0.2.8

Comment: You need to add `users` to the entity in context.

Comment: @DanielShillcock What do you mean by that?

Comment: Your context (`ctx`) is expecting the entity `Entities`, and you are adding `tblUser` to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to add the entity `Users` within an `Entities` context. See below

```
public void BulkInsertUsers(IEnumerable<tblUsers> users)
{
    using (var ctx = new tblUsers())
    {
        // users is detached from database, so we need to add it
        ctx.Attach(users); 
        // Specify that these are modified entities (may not be necessary for BulkInsert)
        // I don't know what properties users contain, so used Name
        ctx.Entry(tblUsers).Property(a => a.Name).IsModified = true;
        ctx.BulkInsert(users);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Something to think about... You could make a generic method to BulkInsert different entities. This may help you out: [A generic way to save an entity in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14429182/1350913)